# Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Tengo una funcion en un clase de swift donde llamo a otra de una clase diferente.

```swift
var imageBase64:String? = -CADENA DE BASE64-

@objc fileprivate func handleContinue(){
        //self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        let obj : ViewControllerWebView = ViewControllerWebView();
        obj.sendFirm(base64: imageBase64!)
        
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
```

con ese evento llamo a la funcion sendFirm

```swift
public func sendFirm(base64: String){
        print("click firma");
        var bas : String! = nil;
        bas = base64;
        //print(bas);
        WebView.evaluateJavaScript("getFirma('\(bas)')") { (result,error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                }
        }
        
    }
```

y esa funcion envia la cadena hacia el webview, pero al ejecutar la funcion webview;
me arroja el error

```swift
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file , line 132
```

Alguna solucion...

Comment: puedes colocar un breakpoint y luego usar po "variable name" ,  normalmente ese error es porque tienes un valor que es nil, dime por que haces un dismiss?

Answer (score 1):

Si el valor no es obligatorio entonces no tendría sentido que evalúes una cadena en el `WebView` si es `null`.
Entonces en esta función deberías validar si es diferente de `null` para llamar a la función:

```
@objc fileprivate func handleContinue(){
        //self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        let obj : ViewControllerWebView = ViewControllerWebView();
        if imageBase64 != nil {
            obj.sendFirm(base64: imageBase64!)
        } else {
        //Puede ir un alert
        }
        
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
```

No es recomendable que hagas `unwrap !` directamente porque te arrojan esos errores, lo recomendable es validar siempre, por lo general recomiendo utilizar `guard`:

```
guard let variableNoNull = imageBase64 else { return }

obj.sendFirm(base64: variableNoNull)
```

Adicional a esto puedes revisar como instancias un `ViewController`:

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identificadorTuViewController") as? TuViewController

guard let variableNoNull = imageBase64 else { return }
controller.sendFirm(base64: variableNoNull)
```

Puede ser que estás accediendo a tu `WebView` que no se ha creado y por es `null`

Comment: Gracias por respondes, el tema es que si llega la cadena a la funcion sendFirm, la puedo imprimir, por lo que se que no es null, no entiendo el por que si si llega la cadena, y el error encuentra un nulo, modifiqué la variable basa y sigue el error

Comment: @Jack Agregué en la respuesta como debes instanciar un `ViewController` puede ser por eso que el `webview` sea `null`.